Problem auth0 to authenticate my Laravel 9 app
I'm using auth0 to authenticate my Laravel 9 app until a month ago everything worked recently but when a user logs in he receives the invalid state error.
The error occurs here..
if (null !== $this->auth0->getExchangeParameters()) {

            $this->auth0->exchange();
        }

Complete code :
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth0\SDK\Auth0;
use Auth0\SDK\Configuration\SdkConfiguration;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Employee;

class Auth0Controller extends Controller
{
    public $auth0;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $configuration = new SdkConfiguration(
            domain: '***',
            clientId: '***',
            clientSecret: '***',
            cookieSecret: 'test-laravel 855',
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8000/callback'
        );

        $this->auth0 = new Auth0($configuration);
    }

    public function auth0()
    {
        $session = $this->auth0->getCredentials();

        if (null === $session || $session->accessTokenExpired) {

            header('Location: ' . $this->auth0->login());
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function callback(Request $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        if (null !== $this->auth0->getExchangeParameters()) {

            $this->auth0->exchange();
        }

        $user = $this->auth0->getCredentials()?->user;

        return response()->json($user);
}
}

I've tried everything, I hope you can help me because I don't understand where the problem is, thanks
